# Rails scope that filters based on the average of a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So, I have a restaurants model, and a restaurant has many reviews, and each review has an integer rating, 1-5. I have a feature that allows users to filter a list of restaurants by a minimum rating, but currently, it grabs them all before filtering then uses a Ruby select statement to eliminate the ones I don't want. I would like to switch this to a cleaner solution that lets SQL do the filtering, but I'm having difficulties figuring out how to do that with a scope.

I've got this, but it gives me a "misuse of aggregate function AVG()" error:

```
scope :min_rating, -> (rating) { joins(:reviews).where('AVG(reviews.rating) > ?', rating)  if rating}
```

What is the correct syntax for this scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `.group("restaurants.id")` or similar to tell it which sets of reviews to put together when calculating the average, and then move it to a `.having` condition (which is applied after that grouping):

```
scope :min_rating, -> (rating) { joins(:reviews).group("restaurants.id").having('AVG(reviews.rating) > ?', rating) if rating }
```

However, this is a good example of a situation where denormalizing your data may make sense -- adding an `average_rating` column to `restaurants`, and recalculating that each time a review is saved. Unlike the grouped calculation, that column can be indexed, and filtered on efficiently -- at the cost of more effort when storing reviews; it's a trade-off.